# git repository clone failed. Connection Reset

Tags: eclipse, git, bitbucket, git-clone

I am using Bit bucket as my hosting site for the distributed version control systems (DVCS) Git.

While Cloning the project and bringing into my eclipse it is giving me the error:

```
Git repository clone failed.
Connection reset
```

While in wizard it does import till 50% Of my project and as soon as it reach 50 it gives me error.

I am doing it directly from `Eclipse[import->Projects from Git-> entering my URL]` without "`git command line`".

I even did `window-->Preferences->Team->Git->Configurations->User Settings`.
When I entered my name & ID but this also isn't helping.

I am unable to Clone in my project please help me with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The name and ID would work only if you are using an https url:

```
 https://username@bitbucket.org/username/yourrepo.git
```

If that fails, you can try and [set up ssh keys in Egit config](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide/Remote#Eclipse_SSH_Configuration), in order to use an ssh url for your repo:

```
git@bitbucket.org:vonc/test.git
```

Comment: VonC Thanks for replying. But I did tried setting up ssh keys. But that also seems not working for Me.

Comment: @DevFreak do you have any error message when you try the ssh url?

Comment: It is giving me the same error as same before : Git repository clone failed.
Connection reset